# Xcode Intel compiler icc cannot find #include <algorithm>

Tags: xcode, intel, icc

Hi I'm trying to compile a gcc based code on Xcode with the icc compiler (11.1.088)
but i have the following error:

```
catastrophic error: could not open source file "algorithm"
```

After looking to this file, it is located in the gcc include directory, but i get hundreds of errors...

Does anyone have suggestions ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What do you have set as your base SDK ? And what version of Xcode ?

FWIW I just tried a test with Xcode 3.2.3 and ICC 11.1 (under OS X 10.6 of course) - created a new C++ console application using the standard Xcode template, added `#include <algorithm>` to main.cc, switched from the default gcc 4.2 to ICC, and it compiles and runs without warnings or errors. The base SDK is the system default (10.6).

It may just be that you have a bad installation of Xcode and/or ICC, or perhaps you have changed a project setting such as base SDK, and this is causing problems.

Comment: Hello, thaks for your test. I use xcode 3.2.3, the base sdk is 10.5. I try to compile a cross platform static library.

Comment: @Ziggy: OK, try 10.6 and see if that works, then if it does you've narrowed the problem down to building with ICC and the 10.5 SDK. It may be that you have to build two libraries: a 10.5 version with gcc and a 10.6 version with ICC (assuming that you have a real need to use ICC ?).

Comment: Hello, tested a simple console app with no problem. Son install is correct. Can't figure out why in my project it failed. prefix header order perhaps ?

Comment: @Ziggy: try looking at the commands that are being generated during a build - anything which might affect the include search paths etc (`-I`, `-iquote`, `-isystem`, etc). Compare a project that works with a project that doesn't work.

Comment: hi, tested without setting the "ICC_PRECOMPILE_PREFIX_HEADER = YES" no more problem with <algorithm> but of course it failed faraway else. Anyway no prefix header is not an option.
I'll test as you said. thanks for your help.

Comment: I finally found what happened :) There where a .c file that where treated by xcode as a .c.c file (command + i on the file show me that). setting it as a real .c file corrected the problem. XCode is very annoying sometimes....

Comment: @Ziggy: well done - I've never seen that problem before but yes, sometimes it takes a little detective work to debug this kind of build problem, with Xcode or any other IDE or build system.

Answer (score 2):

I was having a really stubborn error very similar to this question but with a different solution.

> Algorithm: No such file or directory

My solution:

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
#include <algorithm>
#endif
```

I had the `#include` in a prefix header file (such as the .pch file Xcode gives you in a new project) which was causing it to be included in an Objective-C file, and apparently `algorithm` is C++ only. Either make sure all your Objective-C files are Objective-C++ (.mm) or add that directive to make sure it doesn't get included in those files.

Answer (score 0):

This problem occurred on my machine, while developing an iOS app.
Xcode Version 4.6.3 (4H1503) & iOS version 6.0

I'm using AppCode for development and the IDE added (by accident) the following import statement:

```
#import <c++/4.2.1/ext/algorithm>
```

Answer (score 0):

I met this error too, I just forget to change the source from .m to .mm. so, if adjust C++ complier cannot work, try to change the source file.

Comment: There's already an answer here that says this.  I don't think this answer really adds anything new, just a "me too".