# Intel C++ compiler and cannot open stdarg.h on OS X

Tags: xcode, macos, compiler-construction, compiler-errors, icc

OS X 10.6.8, XCode 3.2.6, Base SDK 10.5, Intel Compiler 11.1

I am getting a weird message when I try to compile that says:

`catastrophic error: could not open source file "stdarg.h"`

I am using a PCH, I did find: [Xcode Intel compiler icc cannot find #include <algorithm>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4244727/xcode-intel-compiler-icc-cannot-find-include-algorithm)

which is a similar issue and I think that the source file type is set to `.c.c` instead of `.c`

From what I can see stdarg.h is:

```
/* This file is public domain.  */
/* GCC uses its own copy of this header */
#if defined(__GNUC__)
    #include_next <stdarg.h>
#elif defined(__MWERKS__)
    #include "mw_stdarg.h"
#else
    #error "This header only supports __MWERKS__."
#endif
```

so must be *GNUC* is defined, obviously.

Can anyone help me figure out how to better compile since this works without changes in GCC 4.0? Is there a global way one might have XCode re-evaluate the source file type to not be `.c.c` or `.cpp.cpp` I am not even sure how this would happen.

Also, is there a `#define` that I can check to see if the Intel compilers are being used to make special cases if I need to?

Comment: I looked at a few of the files referenced in the build results and looking at the `source file type` in XCode it says `source.c.c` and I think if I change that to `source.c` that compiler error goes away.

Comment: Go ahead and answer your own question... not a lot of people are going to be using a similar setup.

Comment: @Grady - Do you have any idea why files can be treated as `c.c` or `.c` as well as `.cpp.cpp` and `.cpp`? I have no concept of why `.c.c` and `.cpp.cpp` is even valid

Comment: just how Xcode used to work I guess? ours is not to reason why; ours is to guess and try.

Answer (score 0):

I looked at a few of the files referenced in the build results and looking at the source file type in XCode it says source.c.c and I think if I change that to source.c that compiler error goes away.